# My ubuntu terminal is frozen and I can't bring it back

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

I installed this `ng-commom` and used the command `script output.txt` to save my terminal output to a file, but immediately after that my terminal froze. I have restarted the machine, turned off, and nothing seems to bring the terminal back.

It's like this, forever. I can't type anything, CTRL+C doesn't work, nor does CTRL+Q, nothing works... I don't know what else to do:

[image: terminal]

running on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: How did you install `ng-common`? … It might have messed up [`libtinfo6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libtinfo6) installed version … Your terminal might not be frozen per se but rather not updating/refreshing correctly ... So try reinstalling Gnome terminal with `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal` e.g. through rescue mode.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with your terminal - rather than with the program that's running *inside* the terminal? Can you access the terminal's settings menu? If so, have you tried setting the command to a different shell (such as /bin/sh)?

Comment: @Raffa I installed ng-common with `sudo apt-get install ng-common` and then I ran `script output.txt`. Immediatelly after that, terminal stopped woking. Even if I turn off the machine and turn on again, problem's still there. Tried to run `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal` through recovery mode as root but it didn't solve the issue. It says "1 package reinstalled" but at the end it shows an error "unable to locate archive.ubuntu.com". I'm kind of hopeless here

Comment: "unable to locate archive.ubuntu.com" ... You need to connect to internet first :-) then try reinstalling gnome-terminal

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76619893/2147690

QUOTE:

1. Go to /home/USER
2. Show hidden files
3. Open .bashrc
4. Remove last line Angular ... source <>